# static variable lifetime

Tags: actionscript-3, compilation

Suppose I have a static variable in a class:

```
class Example {
    public static var one:One = new One;
}
```

Will 'one' being instanciated at my **program startup** (even if I never use it), or just at the first time I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess if you ask the question, it's because you only want the object to be created if you use it. In that case, what you should do is implement lazy creation of the object. Something like that would work:

```
class Example {

    private static var one_:One = null;

    public static function get one():One {
        if (!one_) one_ = new One();
        return one_;
    }

    // If the variable is not read-only, you also need a setter:
    public static function set one(v:One):void {
        one_ = v;
    }

}
```

Now you are sure that `one` will only be created if you directly refers to it using `Example.one` in your code.

Comment: A simple Singleton, right? I've heard its not a good practice to use a Singleton. But I didn't understand why.

Comment: There's no general rule about it, it depends on what you are trying to do. But this is not a singleton pattern anyway, just a static variable (which also may or may not be a good idea, depending on your needs).

Answer (score 0):

First time you will use the Class `Example`

Answer (score 0):

It'd be at startup. But there should be "links" to this class.

- direct usage of this class somewhere in code
- you have `imports` with this class

So if this class compiled-in, it'd instantiated at start-up.

Correct me if I'm wrong.

Actually it's really easy to test :)